# How to set UISegmentedControl w/o calling method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedController to allow a user to choose which order they want slides in my app to show up. Im wondering if anyone knows of a method to set it other than value did change. I have other methods that keep getting triggered in viewDidLoad while its being set to their previously selected index. I don't want the other methods triggered until a user changes it. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be adding boolean to your class, e.g. canTrigger. And you can set it to YES, once user changes.